# How to work with some docker containers together nginx+mysql+laravel+redis+memcache?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I need to configure a docker image which has:
two nginx's
master/slave redis

I tried to build this from hub.docker.com one by one. And I read that I can combine them into one network.

What tools should I use to build this configuration by one command?
Should I read more about docker-compose?
I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Docker`'s approach is to have single process for single container, so you put each service into separate container. Then you come to a point, when you need to decide, how to manage them all.

There are lots of container orchestrating solutions, like `docker-compose`, `docker-swarm`, `k8n` and others, but but I strongly recommend starting with easiest one - `docker-compose`.

You just write single configuration file, `docker-compose.yml`, where declare all your services/container. And then let `docker-compose up` do the job. It will create necessary volumes and networks, thus your containers will be linked together.

Enjoy: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: thank you so much.
Didn`t know that compose creates necessary volumes and networks